# How to write the difficult format string to dataframe via splitting '|' in each string

Tags: python, dataframe, python-re

I have several strings:

```
str1 = 'ABC ; BC /contain/lower | ABC ; BC /notsame | ABC ; BC /similar\n'
str2 = 'AB ; FC /notsame\n'
```

How can I put those strings to dataframe like

| word1 | word2 | relation1 | relation2 | relation3 | relation4 | relation5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | BC | /contain/lower | /notsame | /similar | NaN | NaN |
| AB | FC | /notsame | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Thanks so much for any suggestion.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Did you even try `.split('|')` to create list of lines? And next you could extend it with other list of lines - and at the end you could convert this list to `DataFrame`.

Comment: or maybe you should first conver it to string `'ABC BC /contain/lower /notsame /similar'` and later split to list `['ABC', 'BC', '/contain/lower', '/notsame', '/similar']` and add to list. So all work should be done with normal function, not with `pandas`

Answer (score 1):

you can create`dataframe` from your given `string` as this:

**code**

```
def str2df(your_str):
    str_ = your_str.split('|')
    for i in range(len(str_)):
        if i == 0 :
            pass
        else:
            str_[i] = str_[i].replace('ABC ; BC ','')
            str_[i] = str_[i].replace('\n','')
    
    _str = str_[0].split(';')
    first_str = [_str[0].strip()]
    sec_str = _str[1].strip().split()
    last_str = str_[1:]
    final_str = first_str + sec_str + last_str
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(final_str).T
    col_names = ["word1", "word2", "relation1", "relation2", 
                 "relation3","relation4", "relation5"]
    df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns,col_names)))
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    str1 = 'ABC ; BC /contain/lower | ABC ; BC /notsame | ABC ; BC /similar\n'
    str2 = 'AB ; FC /notsame\n'

    print(str2df(str1))
    print(str2df(str2))
```

**result**

```
print(str2df(str1))
  word1 word2       relation1   relation2  relation3
0   ABC    BC  /contain/lower   /notsame    /similar

print(str2df(str2))
  word1 word2 relation1
0    AB    FC  /notsame
```

If you want to merge the `dataframes`, you can use `concat` as following:

```
concat_df = pd.concat([str2df(str1),str2df(str2)])
print(concat_df)

  word1 word2       relation1   relation2  relation3
0   ABC    BC  /contain/lower   /notsame    /similar
0    AB    FC        /notsame         NaN        NaN
```